# Google colab buildozer giving error when trying to build apk "buildozer failed to execute the last command"

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I am new to kivy and buildozer. I made an app that used csv files on kivy, and tried to build it, but then found out that csv was blacklisted. Then I changed it to use TXT file instead, but it is still giving me an error. I tried this on a virtual machine running ubuntu first but then changed to use google colab, neither of them worked. Then as a final attempt, I tried to use the hello world app to be build, which is also giving me an error. I am trying to understand the logs, but I have no  clue what the error is!

I first tried using a VM running UBUNTU which did not work. Then I switched to google colab and it was not working as well. I tried with three different codes, 2 were my main program, one uses csv file and other uses txt file, but then I tried to build a hello world kivy program, which did not work either!

```
I have added the error log onto the pastebin website:
https://pastebin.com/fxNXDvX1
I have zero clue what to do here,
if any other info needed I will provide it
```